# Docker volume mount: Host mount point directory is also visible inside container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

In our customized OS (Buildroot based), I am trying to volume mount like here:

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  tester:
    image: test:0.0.5
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - /home/chirag/Workspace/docker/docker-tests/lest:/foo/bar
      - /home/chirag/Workspace/docker/docker-tests/backup:/data/db
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM < some base image >

RUN mkdir -p /data/db
RUN mkdir -p /foo/bar

CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

For some reasons inside the container:

- backup (from host) is getting appended i.e. /data/db/backup/< content of backup >

  Instead it should be /data/db/< content of backup >
- This issue is not reproduced in other volume i.e. /foo/bar/< content of lest >

Any pointers?

Comment: Hope the `backup` directory on host does not contain another `backup` directory. Like `/home/chirag/Workspace/docker/docker-tests/backup/backup`.

Comment: No, there isnt any subdirectory named "backup" inside parent "backup" directory